# How to get all anchors with attribute rel="no" using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I want to get all anchor elements on my page where the attribute "rel" exists and where it has the value "no".

How can I do this using jQuery?

I've tried something using the find method

```
 var list = [];

$(parentElement).find('[rel]').each(function(index){
    if (this.attr("rel")) list.push(this);
});
```

Can this be done easier?

Comment: wait, is that "no" the value of `rel` or the content of the anchor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [element selector](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/) `a` combined with the [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) `[rel=no]`:

```
$('a[rel=no]');
```

If you want only anchor elements that are links (not bookmarks), also use the [has attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/) `[href]`:

```
$('a[href][rel=no]');
```

Comment: I do remember something that required attribute selectors in jQuery to *always have quoted values* (i.e. `[rel="no"]`) after some specific version. Keep forgetting which though.

Comment: @RichardNeilIlagan: That's only required if the value contains separators. Ref: *"Can be either an unquoted single word or a quoted string"*

Comment: ~ ah, got me there. I think I was misinterpreting the second paragraph here: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/

Answer (score 2):

You probably want the [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
$('a[rel=no]')
```

Answer (score 1):

if I understood what you want try this:

```
$('a[rel="no"]');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var anchorArray = $("a[rel='no']");
```